# Error using arrays in shell script

Tags: shell, unix

I was testing a shell script in which arrays were used.
This is an example taken from [tutorialspoint](http://www.tutorialspoint.com)

```
#!/bin/sh

NAME[0]="Zara"
NAME[1]="Qadir"
NAME[2]="Mahnaz"
NAME[3]="Ayan"
NAME[4]="Daisy"
echo "First Index: ${NAME[0]}"
echo "Second Index: ${NAME[1]}"
```

But I am getting this error
test.sh: 3: test.sh: NAME[0]=Zara: not found
test.sh: 4: test.sh: NAME[1]=Qadir: not found
test.sh: 5: test.sh: NAME[2]=Mahnaz: not found
test.sh: 6: test.sh: NAME[3]=Ayan: not found
test.sh: 7: test.sh: NAME[4]=Daisy: not found
test.sh: 8: test.sh: Bad substitution

The link to the exact page is [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-using-arrays.htm)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The shebang is wrong, this only works in specific shells, e.g. `bash`.

Comment: It's working when i execute the code as >  bash test.sh

Answer (score 1):

Simple. You just need to run as -

```
bash script_name.sh
```